# Coda 2 still publishes files in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore, coda

I use git for source control in coda 2. I have one file that I need to be different on my local machine, but even when I include it in .gitignore, coda still pushes it to the master.

The reason I need to ignore this file, is because it references localhost rather than 0.0.0.0 for the web server. Is there an easier way to do this, or do I just need to push with the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the terminal, but only briefly. The following post covers this in more detail: [Ignore files that have already been committed to a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)